Why is concept and class having same name disallowed
Maybe there is a very simple reason but I so far couldn't figure out. Why does the standard not allow it? Concepts can't be used for scope resolution, and one can't use concepts as function parameters without auto. So I don't see at what places would it be impossible for the compiler to tell clearly whether the programmer wanted to use the concept or the type, even though they have the same name.
SomeConcept::Whatever                 // not possible
void someFunc( SomeConcept auto& x )  // auto required
template<SomeConcept T>               // concept instead of "typename"

"Easier to parse" I don't think is enough reason.

There is at least one case where the compiler would not be able to distinguish the meaning: in a template parameter, the identifier SomeConcept could be a concept, or a non-type template parameter of class type.
e.g., the following is valid:
struct SomeConcept {};
template<SomeConcept T> void f() {}

// ... later used like
f<SomeConcept{}>();


I see. I forgot about that feature, I don't think I ever used it. But I had name-conflict with concept and class and researching I found people doing weird stuff like adding _c suffix to concepts or putting them into namespace Concepts or naming them with snake_case, so it made me wonder what was the point of disallowing same-name. Anyway, my question is answered, thanks!

Well this is also why you should have namespaces. Nothing prevents you from putting your concepts in a traits/concept namespace
